# Identify and Style the Menu Item for the Current Page

Tags: php

I am having trouble making the current item selected in my menu, here is the code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kurchi_pages ORDER BY id LIMIT 1,5";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    $site_url = "http://swenflea/swenflea.com/";

    if(!isset($_GET['page']) || !isset($_GET['post'])) {
        echo '<li id="current"><a href="' . $site_url . '">Home</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $site_url . '">Home</a></li>';
    }


    if ( isset($_GET['page'] ) || isset($_GET['post'] )) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        if ($_GET['page'] != "" . $row["url"] . "" || isset($_GET['page'] ) ) 
        {
            $itemis = '<li><a href="' . $site_url . '' . $row['url'] . '/">' . $row['nav_name'] . '</a></li>'; 
        } else {
            $itemis = '<li id="current"><a href="' . $site_url . '' . $row['url'] . '/">' . $row['nav_name'] . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo $itemis;
        }
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $site_url . '' . $row['url'] . '/">' . $row['nav_name'] . '</a></li>'; 
    }
    }
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: hello, i couldnt get this code, what this code does..?  **if ($_GET['page'] != "" . $row["url"] . "" || isset($_GET['page'] ) )** Is that working..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Page Configuration Values
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kurchi_pages ORDER BY id LIMIT 1,5";
$site_url = "http://swenflea/swenflea.com/";

# If Neither PAGE or POST are set, mark the HOME link as CURRENT
echo '<li'.( !isset( $_GET['page'] ) && !isset( $_GET['post'] ) ? ' id="current"' : '' ).'><a href="' . $site_url . '">Home</a></li>';
echo 'DEBUG: !isset( $_GET[\'page\'] ) = '.!isset( $_GET['page'] );
echo 'DEBUG: !isset( $_GET[\'post\'] ) = '.!isset( $_GET['post'] );

# Perform the SQL Query
$res = mysql_query( $sql );

# Check the SQL Result
if( !$res )
  die( 'ERROR: Unable to Retrieve Pages from Database' );
if( mysql_num_rows( $res )==0 )
  die( 'ERROR: No Pages Retrieved from Database' );

# Loop through the Rows
  echo 'DEBUG: $_GET[\'page\'] = '.( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '--' );
  echo 'DEBUG: $_GET[\'post\'] = '.( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ? $_GET['post'] : '--' );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ){
  echo 'DEBUG: $row[\'url\'] = '.$row['url'];
  echo 'DEBUG: Match $_GET[\'page\'] = '.( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page']==$row['url'] );
  echo 'DEBUG: Match $_GET[\'post\'] = '.( isset( $_GET['post'] ) && $_GET['post']==$row['url'] );
  $attrs = '';
  if( ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page']==$row['url'] )
      || ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) && $_GET['post']==$row['url'] ) ){
   # Page OR Post Requested - Matches Row
    $attrs = ' id="current"';
  }
  echo '<li'.$attrs.'><a href="'.$site_url.$row['url'].'">'.$row['nav_name'].'</a></li>';
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Added Debug Messages to code to identify why it is not working as expected.

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed one bug in my code, added further Debug Messages.

Comment: Sorry didn't work, on homepage all links are selected, on any other page all pages except home are selected

Comment: I have added debug messages - any line starting with `echo 'DEBUG:...` to help you see what different variables have at different stages. Use that to determine why this code is not behaving as expected.

Comment: here is the output code: DEBUG: !isset( $_GET["page"] ) = 1DEBUG: !isset( $_GET["post"] ) = DEBUG: $row['url'] = blogDEBUG: Match $_GET["page"] = DEBUG: Match $_GET["post"] = 
Notice: Undefined variable: attrs in functions.php on line 441
DEBUG: $row['url'] = contactDEBUG: Match $_GET["page"] = DEBUG: Match $_GET["post"] = 
Notice: Undefined variable: attrs in functions.php on line 441

Comment: OK, fixed the bits the "*Notice: Undefined variable: attrs in functions.php on line 441*" Errors. Also added another couple of DEBUG messages. Try the above code again and let me know the messages it returns (as you just did).

Comment: sorry still getting: Notice: Undefined variable: attrs in functions.php

Comment: Have you replaced the old code from above with the new code? I cannot see how that error could still be occurring with this new code.

Comment: @swenflea: OK, when you are looking at a Blog Post, what are the DEBUG messages showing? What is the value being shown as that of `$_GET['page']` and `$_GET['post']` and do they match any of the values retrieved from SQL in the `$row['url']` field? This is Coding/Testing 101.

Comment: That is not what I asked. What are the current DEBUG messages showing?

Comment: Yes it is... "$_GET['page'] and $_GET['post'] and do they match any of the values retrieved from SQL in the $row['url'] field?" $_GET['post'] should equal the posts url not $row['url']. 

Sorry for not telling you earlier, I feel like an ideot

Comment: DEBUG CODE: DEBUG: !isset( $_GET['page'] ) = 1DEBUG: !isset( $_GET['post'] ) = DEBUG: $_GET['page'] = --DEBUG: $_GET['post'] = iphone-5DEBUG: $row['url'] = blogDEBUG: Match $_GET['page'] = DEBUG: Match $_GET['post'] = DEBUG: $row['url'] = contactDEBUG: Match $_GET['page'] = DEBUG: Match $_GET['post'] =

Answer (score 0):

The code above from Lucanos: and url is http://yoursite.com/single.php?post=something&page=blog